# Creating groupings based on criteria

Tags: sql, netezza, gaps-and-islands

Hoping to get some assistance with the following gaps and islands problem

I have the following sample dataset:

| MEM_ID | CLM_ID | ADM_DT | DCHG_DT | PROV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 112 | 01-01-2021 | 02-01-2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 113 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 114 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 115 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 116 | 02-15-2021 | 02-15-2021 | 2 |
| 1 | 117 | 02-15-2021 | 02-15-2021 | 3 |
| 1 | 118 | 02-16-2021 | 02-16-2021 | 3 |
| 2 | 211 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 |
| 2 | 212 | 03-01-2021 | 03-01-2021 | 2 |
| 3 | 311 | 02-01-2021 | 02-01-2021 | 1 |
| 3 | 312 | 02-01-2021 | 02-01-2021 | 2 |

What I am trying to accomplish is the following:

Based on the unique combination of a MEM_ID,PROV,and ADM_DT, I want to group the events into 1. I also need to group any additional events from the same MEM_ID and PROV if the DCHG_DT is the same as the ADM_DT or up to 1 day ahead.

The end result should look like this:

| MEM_ID | CLM_ID | ADM_DT | DCHG_DT | PROV | GROUP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 112 | 01-01-2021 | 02-01-2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 113 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 114 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 115 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 116 | 02-15-2021 | 02-15-2021 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 117 | 02-15-2021 | 02-15-2021 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 118 | 02-16-2021 | 02-16-2021 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 211 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 212 | 03-01-2021 | 03-01-2021 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 311 | 02-01-2021 | 02-01-2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 312 | 02-01-2021 | 02-01-2021 | 2 | 2 |

In the expected output, the first 5 records for MEM_ID 1 was grouped into group 1 because it meets the criteria of having the same MEM_ID,PROV, and ADM_DT combination. Records 6 and 7 have the same MEM_ID and ADM_DT combination but different PROV, therefore they are broken into groups 2 and 3. Record 8 has the same combination of MEM_ID and PROV but the ADM_DT is different to that of Record 7. However because the ADM_DT from record 8 is within 1 day of the DCHG_DT from record 7, it is considered the same event and assigned group 3. The rest of the data points are pretty straight forward on why they are grouped the way they are.

I have attempted the following code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MEM_ID
    , PROV
    , CLM_ID
    , ADM_DT
    , DCHG_DT
    , sum(ISSTART) OVER (PARTITION BY MEM_ID, ADM_DT ORDER BY ADM_DT, DCHG_DT rows unbounded preceding) AS GROUP

FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT MEM_ID
        , PROV
        , CLM_ID
        , ADM_DT
        , DCHG_DT
        , CASE 
            WHEN PROV = LAG(PROV) OVER (PARTITION BY MEM_ID ORDER BY ADM_DT, DCHG_DT)
                AND (
                        (
                        ADM_DT = LAG(DCHG_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY MEM_ID ORDER BY ADM_DT, DCHG_DT)
                        )
                    OR (
                        ADM_DT = LAG(DCHG_DT + 1) OVER (PARTITION BY MEM_ID ORDER BY ADM_DT, DCHG_DT)
                        )
                    )
                THEN 0
            ELSE 1
            END AS ISSTART
    
    FROM c1
    ) t
```

However this is giving me errors in grouping.

Using the above code i get something similar to this:

| MEM_ID | CLM_ID | ADM_DT | DCHG_DT | PROV | GROUP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 112 | 01-01-2021 | 02-01-2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 113 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 114 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 115 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 116 | 02-15-2021 | 02-15-2021 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 117 | 02-15-2021 | 02-15-2021 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 118 | 02-16-2021 | 02-16-2021 | 3 | 1 |

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Should a chain of admits on consecutive dates be in the same group or does that only apply to the first two dates in such a series?

Comment: @shawnt00 chain of admits on consecutive dates should be in the same group. the chain should also include any CLM_ID where the ADM_DT and PROV values are the same. Sometimes the DCHG_DT changes so that the lag statement doesnt always apply. Ill update the table accordingly to show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *,
    sum(gap) over (partition by MEM_ID order by ADM_DT, CLM_ID) as grp
from (
    select *,
        case when
                ADM_DT =
                lag(ADM_DT)  over (partition by MEM_ID, PROV order by ADM_DT, CLM_ID)
                or           
            days_between(
                ADM_DT,
                lag(DCHG_DT) over (partition by MEM_ID, PROV order by ADM_DT, CLM_ID)
            ) in (0, 1) -- not sure if zero is valid
            then 0 else 1 end as gap
    from c1
) t
order by MEM_ID, PROV, GRP, ADM_DT
```

If you don't have `days_between()` available then apparently you would just use `when lag(DCHG_DT) over (partition by MEM_ID, PROV order by ADM_DT, CLM_ID) - ADM_DT`

Note that Postgres handles the date math differently but you can try it out https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=95f28f3d57c520d1e45422b588dcdd85

Comment: i tried this code and it mostly captures what i need with the exception of the criteria where the same MEM_ID,PROV, and ADM_DT are the same then it should be chained.

Comment: @CCP So then I think you just check that preceding row has same admit date.

Comment: Thank you for the support. I have incorporated this into my code and it appears to work for most records but not 100%. Despite that, im sure it is something related to the data on hand and Ill have to make some transformations. Marking this as the correct answer nonetheless!